# Finding the average of this problem

Tags: average

There are 100 people in a room. Each one them can eat 4 pies in total. The maximum amount of pies that can be eaten is 400 pies. If 172 pies were eaten, what is the average pie eaten by per person?

I have trouble coming up with the correct algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: $\frac{172}{100}$? Does it have anything to do with the pie eating capacity of the players?

Answer (score 1):

Simply 172/100=1.72 pies per person on average. But may be the wording of the question is not clear enough and there is a deeper problem here that I don't see.